# Spring Security Oauth2 + OIDC (OpenID Connect) OP Initiated/Back Channel logout with Multiple RPs

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, openid, spring-security-oauth2

An Authentication server (OP) with multiple RPs is the architecture. Please check the image below.

[image]

I was able to successfully log out with [RP initiated logout](https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-rpinitiated-1_0.html#:%7E:text=An%20RP%20requests%20that%20the,be%20learned%20via%20other%20mechanisms.) which is if I log out from any of the clients the client(RP) gets logged out and the OP also gets logged out.

Please find OpenID Provider Discovery Metadata;

```
{
    "jwks_uri":"https://<Auth Server URL>/token_keys",
    "subject_types_supported":["public"],
    "end_session_endpoint":"https://<Auth Server URL>/logout",
    "issuer":"https://<Auth Server URL>/oauth/token",
    "authorization_endpoint":"https://<Auth Server URL>/oauth/authorize",
    "token_endpoint":"https://<Auth Server URL>/oauth/token"
}
```

with `"end_session_endpoint"` present in the discovery I was able to do the RP initiated logout using the following code in the clients,

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.method.configuration.EnableGlobalMethodSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.HttpSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.builders.WebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.EnableWebSecurity;
import org.springframework.security.config.annotation.web.configuration.WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.mapping.GrantedAuthoritiesMapper;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.userinfo.OidcUserRequest;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.oidc.web.logout.OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.registration.ClientRegistrationRepository;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.userinfo.OAuth2UserService;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUser;
import org.springframework.security.oauth2.core.oidc.user.OidcUserAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.web.csrf.CookieCsrfTokenRepository;
import org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.StaticHeadersWriter;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfiguration;
import org.springframework.web.cors.CorsConfigurationSource;
import org.springframework.web.cors.UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource;

import com.nimbusds.jose.shaded.json.JSONArray;

@Configuration
@EnableWebSecurity
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(prePostEnabled = true, jsr250Enabled = true)
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    
    @Autowired
    private ClientRegistrationRepository clientRegistrationRepository;
    
    @Override
    public void configure(WebSecurity web) throws Exception {
        web.ignoring().antMatchers("/assets/**").antMatchers("/assets/bundles/**");
    }
    
     @Bean(name = "oidcUserService")
     OAuth2UserService<OidcUserRequest, OidcUser> oidcUserService() {
         return new CustomOidcUserService();
     }
    
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        
        http.cors().and().headers(headers -> headers.cacheControl().and()
                .addHeaderWriter(new StaticHeadersWriter("X-UA-Compatible", "IE=edge"))
                .frameOptions(frameOptions -> frameOptions.sameOrigin()).httpStrictTransportSecurity())
        .authorizeRequests(authorize -> authorize
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .anyRequest().authenticated())
        .oauth2Login(oauthLogin -> oauthLogin
                .userInfoEndpoint()
                .oidcUserService(this.oidcUserService()))
        .logout(logout -> logout
                .logoutSuccessHandler(oidcLogoutSuccessHandler())
                .invalidateHttpSession(true)
                .clearAuthentication(true)
                .deleteCookies("JSESSIONID","CSRF-TOKEN","XSRF-TOKEN")
                .permitAll())
         .csrf((csrf) -> csrf
                    .csrfTokenRepository(CookieCsrfTokenRepository.withHttpOnlyFalse()));

    }

    private OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler() {
        OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler oidcLogoutSuccessHandler = new OidcClientInitiatedLogoutSuccessHandler(this.clientRegistrationRepository);
        oidcLogoutSuccessHandler.setPostLogoutRedirectUri("{baseUrl}");
        return oidcLogoutSuccessHandler;
     }
    
    @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "DELETE", "OPTIONS"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }

}
```

But I have no idea how to implement OP initiated Logot, which logs out all the clients under the OP if the OP session expires or OP gets logged out. Are there any examples available? I have been researching for this for few days and found about having another key called  `"check_session_iframe"` but could not find proper documentation from spring. Please share if you have any examples. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

If the OP's metadata does not include a `check_session_iframe` `frontchannel_logout_supported` or `backchannel_logout_supported`, then it simply does not support single logout, which would trigger a logout at the clients aka "OP initiated logout".

---

The `check_session_iframe` contains an URL under the control of the OP. The client will embed this URL as an iframe, also called OP iframe. The OP iframe has access to the User Agent state at the OpenID provider (since it is the same domain). The client will create another iframe, the RP iframe, to send postMessage requests to the OP iframe for checking the session status. The OP iframe will then respond with a postMessage request to the RP iframe with the result (changed, unchanged or error).

Regarding the client part of the session management specification the only thing you have to do is to embed the OP iframe, give it an id so that you can send postMessage requests to it and handle postMessage requests from it within your RP iframe. Check out the pseudo code in the specification:
https://openid.net/specs/openid-connect-session-1_0.html#RPiframe

Comment: I can include `check_session_iframe` in the metadata, but how does it work, is there any example? `check_session_iframe` contains a URL and how does it implement on the client-side?